# Android indeterminate progress dialog progress bar style

Tags: android, android-theme

I cannot find the reason why the style of progress bar shown inside indeterminate ProgressDialog differs between Android 22 and 23.

Let's take a very simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example.com.progressbarcolor.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_progress"
        android:text="Show progres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Pressing the button displays ProgressDialog:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
progressDialog.show();
```

The style of the app is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And finally the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.progressbarcolor"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

As you can see on the images below both apps display the same progress bar when used directly inside layout but the colors are different inside ProgressDialog.

On Android 22, the progress dialog shows green progress bar instead of red one.

Nexus 5, API 22

[image: Nexus 5 - API 22]

Nexus 5X, API 23

[image: Nexus 5X - API 23]

Comment: AFAIK the appcompat library never changes the ProgressDialog's ProgressBar style ... you have to build your own dialog ...

Comment: do you have different theme in different styles.xml??

Comment: There is only one theme for all versions.

Comment: I have even tested by removing AppCompat library, making the MainActivity extend classic Android Activity and specifying the base style as android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar. Still the same. And I see no difference in the default styles bewteen 22 and 23 regarding progress bar (dialog) area.

Answer (score 5):

Add this in Your Style :

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <!-- Used for the buttons -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!-- Used for the title and text -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <!-- Used for the background -->
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

and set to the dialog :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
```

Comment: Looks like applying the changes to the progress but still: the dialog doesn't span the whole width available and on Android 19 it is even worse, you seen some white border under the progress and above the dimmed background.

Comment: <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item> and <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> fixes the border.